# Constructing query that contains a mapping table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a very simple cms. 
The two objects in it are **articles** and **tags**
Here is the db schema i have currently:

[image: The scheema ERD]

Using this I can get a list of articles by tags `SELECT ... WHERE web_tag.Name = 'News'`

---

## Question

How can I get a list of articles which **DONOT** contain a tag.
I tried doing

```
SELECT ... WHERE web_tag.Name != 'News'
```

This work if the article has only one tag. It won't work if the article has more than one tag obviously

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it

```
SELECT a.id_article, a.name
  FROM web_article a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
    FROM web_tag_to_article ta JOIN web_tag t
      ON ta.id_tag = t.id_tag
   WHERE id_article = a.id_article
     AND t.name = 'News'
)
```

or

```
SELECT id_article, name
  FROM web_article
 WHERE id_article NOT IN
(
  SELECT id_article
    FROM web_tag_to_article ta JOIN web_tag t
      ON ta.id_tag = t.id_tag
   GROUP BY id_article
  HAVING MAX(t.name = 'News') = 1
)
```

or

```
SELECT a.id_article, a.name
  FROM web_article a LEFT JOIN web_tag_to_article ta 
    ON a.id_article = ta.id_article LEFT JOIN web_tag t
    ON ta.id_tag = t.id_tag
 GROUP BY a.id_article, a.name
HAVING MAX(COALESCE(t.name,'') = 'News') = 0
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bdc12/33)** demo

Comment: hmm... this seems to be pretty inefficient. but oh well, works! thanks.

Comment: @vidhu You're welcome :) See updated answer for alternatives.

Comment: Love the last example. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

another way

select ID_Articles, Name, Slug from web_article where ID_Article in
(select ID_Articles from web_article except
 ( select ID_Article from web_tag_to_Article where ID_Tag in 
   (select ID_Tag from web_tag where name='news')  ) )